# Writing a script to go through directories?

Tags: scripts

I was assigned a database project where the dataset I downloaded, was 50GB. After extracting the dataset I have 31 folders. Each of this 31 folders contain 23 folders. And each of this 23 folders contain 59 (00-59).json data. I need to feed this data to MongoDB. I was writing this command for it:

```
 mongoimport --db twitter --collection twitterCol --file /media/shamsad/1E8A00A88A007E91/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2013-08/08/01/00/00.json
```

But it is tiresome for writing this command for 31*23*59 .json data.
How can I write a script to go through directories, locate jsons and call mongoimport?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No script needed, just `find`:

```
find /media/shamsad/1E8A00A88A007E91/ -name '*.json' \
    -exec  mongoimport --db twitter --collection twitterCol --file {} \;
```

Comment: could you kindly explain what does "name '*.json data' \" this part do?

Comment: @sphoenix `-name '*.json data'` : all files with `json data` extension. `\\` : is used to write a command in two line; so bash will know the following line is a part of same command and not another command;

Comment: @sphoenix what ravexina said. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: I wrote your command in a db_script.sh and ran it. It says    "find: paths must precede expression:  
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
./db_script.sh: line 2: -exec: command not found
"

Comment: @terdon You had `*.json data` where it should just be `*.json`. I fixed it.

Comment: @sphoenix `find` commands must be of the form `find <path> <expression>`, where in this case `/media...` is the path and the rest is the expression. Fix that, then see if it works.

Comment: @sphoenix then you didn't run that command. I'm guessing you used `*.json` instead of `'*.json'`.

Comment: so it should be like this:  find </media/shamsad/1E8A00A88A007E91/ -name '*.json' > 
    <-exec  mongoimport --db twitter --collection twitterCol --file {}> \;

Comment: @sphoenix it should be exactly like I have written in my answer. Just paste it directly into a terminal. I don't understand what you mean with all the `<` and `>` you added. Maybe you'd like to come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) to clarify (if you do, just ping me with `@terdon`).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The angle brackets in my comment indicate a placeholder. I.e. `<path>` -> `media/shamsad/1E8A00A88A007E91/`

Comment: @wjandrea I try to avoid using those as place holders since they can be very dangerous if anyone actually copies them directly (`<` and `>` will overwrite things).

Comment: ...and the \; is simply an ancient ritual in summoning find :)